# Pass server side file to angular's $http.get function

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, ajax, server-side

I want to get a server side JSON file and use it in AJAX get method. Once we have the file, I will be able to display in the grid. Here's the function for that.

It doesn't recognize location until I give 2 and 4 back slashes as shown here

```
$http({
        method:'GET',
        url: '\\\\sample.dce.com\\data\\ping.json'       

    })
    .then(function (res) {
        $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(res.data);
    });
```

However, I get error as follows

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://sample.dce.com/data/ping.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Can someone please help me to show how to get server side file (using c#) at front end using ajax call

Comment: Side note: it is generally better to provide absolute uri (i.e. if you want local file it is better to explicitly specify `file:` as scheme, of maybe "http:.."). Also `\ ` is used for Windows file paths when it looks like you are looking for ftp/http/https/... resource which must use `/`.

Comment: Alexei Levenkov- its a windows file path i am trying to get access to. thats y i have \\ and the file is located on the server

Comment: You obviously can't (as error clearly explains). So you need to figure out what you actually want to achieve and what you are willing to give up to do so (you really can't have CORS between http: and file: locations).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov- so it has to be http location. can you please suggest a way how to achieve that ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov- should i convert the filepath to URL in the server side first ?

Comment: There are thousands existing questions about getting file from server using AJAX and serving  downloadable file with C#. I'm not sure which approaches you've already tried so it is hard to to see what kind of help you need. Try this search - https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+download+ajax to see similar questions... Also figure out what server side framework you use - options vary ....